# Why does cmake return an error when i build my c++ code?

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, clion

I want to start learning OpenGL, so I learnt some C++, installed CLion (JetBrains IDE), and tried to make everything work. I work on Ubuntu 20.04. I checked that freeglut and OpenGL are installed, I don't know what else to do.

This is the `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(OpenGlmessing)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(OpenGlmessing main.cpp)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(${OpenGlmessing} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARY})
```

And the error I got:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target
  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so" which is not built by this
  project.
```

Comment: I think you need to remove ${} from ${OpenGLmessing} on the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to remove "$" inside target_link_libraries

```
target_link_libraries(OpenGlmessing ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARY})
```